# The Merits of Feature Reduction Routines

Tags: r, feature-selection, correlation, pca, boruta

I am interested in learning what routine others use (if any) for Feature Reduction/Selection.

For example, If my data has several thousand features, I typically try {2,3,4} things right away depending on circumstances.

1. Zero variance/Near zero variance

   - Using [R package caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#zero--and-near-zero-variance-predictors), `nzv`
   - I find a v.small percentage is zero variance and a few more are near zero variance.
   - Then by using [nzv$PercentUnique](https://youtu.be/qhvkVxuwvLk?t=385) I may remove the bottom quartile of features depending on the range of PercentUnique's.
2. Correlation to find multicollinearity

   - I find the correlation matrix and [remove values > 0.75](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#identifying-correlated-predictors) and remove.
   - I have seen others use correlations > 0.5 or 0.6, but don't have any references for it.
3. Boruta / Random Forest

   - Love [Boruta package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v036i11) but it takes a while.
   - Then here again use Forward Feature Selection.
4. PCA

   - Depending on the nature of the data I will try PCA last.
   - If the model must be explainable then I skip this.
   - I may use several criteria: 80, 90, 95% error explained
   - Forward Feature selection, look for first ~3:10 orthogonal features

**NOTE**: I am not suggesting this is the best/worst routine but I'm opening the floor to [civil debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_discourse). If you need a definition for *Civil Debate* see Wikipedia.

Comment: honest question, but stackexchange sites like datasciense.se are not for debating things but for objectively defined questions and answers

Comment: @nikos-m  After thinking about your post, I remembered this,   https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34357/why-do-people-prefer-pandas-to-sql  Granted, It is not a code related question like S.E.but on topic. I'm torn...

Comment: This older post discusses the merits of procedures, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/fix-first-two-levels-of-decision-tree  The question becomes, 'are people willing to broaden the scope here?'